# Create a function to transform an array of data into column headers for a table dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, foreach, dynamic-arrays

What I'm trying to do is take a data array of objects and create a function where I can pass the data in and render the column headers and rows dynamically. Here is my sample data:

```
 let revisions = [
        {
          car: {
            id: 1000,
            header: "Toyota"
          },
          revisionDate: {
            header: "Revision Date",
            newValue: "08/24/2021",
            oldValue: "09/15/2020"
          },
          revisionType: {
            header: "Revision Type",
            newValue: "Tool Desc.",
            oldValue: "Tool Number"
          },
          revisionNote: {
            header: "Revision Note",
            newValue: "Delete",
            oldValue: "Delete"
          },
          workStation: {
            header: "Garage",
            newValue: "New garage",
            oldValue: "Old garage"
          }
        }
```

For my function I have tried using 2 for loops, however I cannot seem to figure out how to get the properties in the array. What I've tried:

```
getHeaders(revisions) {
    var prop;
    var rowProp;
    for (rowProp = 0; rowProp < revisions.length; rowProp++)
      if (rowProp >= 0) {
        gridData.push({ header: revisions.header });
      }
    for (prop = 0; prop < revisions.length; prop++) {
      if (prop === "oldValue") {
        gridData.push({ field: "revisionDate", header: revisions.header + " (Existing)" });
      }
      if (prop === "newValue") {
        gridData.push({ field: "revisionDateNew", header: revisions.header + " (New)" });
      }
      else {
        gridData.push(revisions);
      }
    }
    return gridData;
  }
```

Here is the html just in case:

```
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
          {{col.header}}
        </th>
      </tr>
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: looks like you array contains a single item, an object, which contains several several objects. Thus revisions.length is 1 and doesn't contain any of the expected objects you are. using.

Comment: Sorry I was not specific enough, the array is my mock api data and actually has 10 items but eventually will be replaced with an api.

Answer (score 0):

If your objects stay built the same:

```
{
 car:{...},
 revisionDate:{...},
 revisionType:{...},
 revisionNote:{...},
 workStation:{...}
}
```

Then you dont even need to build a function to display that data in a table here is a table layout you could do:

```
 <table>
  <th class="row" >
    <div class="col-2">{{ revisions[0].car.header }}</div>
    <div class="col-2">{{ revisions[0].revisionDate.header }}</div>
    <div class="col-2">{{ revisions[0].revisionType.header }}</div>
    <div class="col-2">{{ revisions[0].revisionNote.header }}</div>
    <div class="col-2">{{ revisions[0].workStation.header }}</div>
  </th>
  <td class="row" *ngFor="let rev of revisions">
    <div class="col-2">{{ rev.car.id }}</div>
    <div class="col-2">{{ rev.revisionDate.newValue }}</div>
    <div class="col-2">{{ rev.revisionType.newValue }}</div>
    <div class="col-2">{{ rev.revisionNote.newValue }}</div>
    <div class="col-2">{{ rev.workStation.newValue }}</div>
  </td>
</table>
```

revisions[0] is used to just get the first object and access the headers for display.  Then after that you use your `*ngFor=""` in order to loop through each object and display the data within those elements.

Comment: Thanks, assuming the data does change such as getting the data from an api in the future, is there a way to create the function to handle that?

Comment: If you are creating your api, I would suggest possibly refactoring the way you have the data set up.  It is kind of confusing the way it is laid out.  Maybe have a getHeaders endpoint and a getData endpoint then go from there, it would be much more simple to display just the headers then.